# Execute code when closing program TaskManager Process

Tags: vb.net, taskmanager

How do I as a person is to "TaskManager> Process" and "End Process", it closes another program along with it, so close the two programs together.

I tried following

```
Private Sub frmAH_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
    If e.CloseReason = CloseReason.UserClosing Then
        Dim pProcess() As Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("CabalMain")
        For Each p As Process In pProcess
            p.Kill()
        Next
        End
    End If
End Sub
```

However, it does not close when you close the game GameGuard, wanted closes the game together.

Comment: Did you debug your code? I didn't quite understood the problem, p.kill is equivalent to the "End Process" on taskmanager.

Comment: SomeNickName all good, yes I wonder if someone tried my program in taskmanager you can close another program along with it? tried it and it run a command to close another.

Comment: What do you mean? When your program is closed you want to close another one right after? From this program that is being closed in the first place?

Comment: Form_FormClosing event doesn't do the trick?
If you're talking about doing that on that "End process" is kinda impossible... for what i've seen in the past, because that kills the process right away, it's like the End statement in vb.net...